# How to create a template used with PHP for web pages

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to create an application that will have some similar looking pages.  I am not sure what is the best way to do this.

Each page will have a header, side bar, content and footer.

The tricky part here is the sections will be similar but not the same.  For example the header can have a combobox and different pages will have different data.  One page will have a textbox.

The data will come from SQL server via PHP.

What would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: If making a template is too broad how do I narrow it down?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using PHP then take a look into http://www.h2o-template.org/ - the templates will allow you to create similar structures and keeping them maintanable most importantly.

You can then have base template which encapsulates all of the similarities and extend sub templates from that which make each page unique.